# Angular module ("myApp",[],[])

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Angular (actually, new in coding).

I have to use both ng-grid and iu.bootstrap, and I would like to know if it's possible to call them in a single module.

I need a datepicker from bootstrap, and the grid from ng-grid.

How can I do?

Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you!!!

Comment: How about u accept one or give us all an up arrow! :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can inject the modules in the dependency list, for example

**angular.module('mudule-name', ['module1', module2']);**

If doesn't use any dependency, then use as follows,

**angular.module('module.name', []);**

Answer (score 2):

When you define your module you can inject as many modules as you would like...

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ng-grid', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

Also you can break your app/solution into multiple modules...

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []);
angular.module('myApp.services', []);
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.directives', 'myApp.services']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example how to do what you're asking about:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngGrid'

]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I have the dependencies named right here, but you simply pass the list of module dependencies in the second argument of the `angular.module` command:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ng-grid'
]);
```